# Using photoshop to complete undersampling in tensorflow object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, photoshop

I'm currently training an object detection model using Tensorflow and I ran into a problem. I don't have enough samples to train my model effectively and it will take me a long time to get more samples. I was wondering if it could be a good idea to complete the remaining samples using photoshop or will I run into issues using this approach?

Comment: Samples is not enough? did you using data augmentation? this can be easily done in python

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with this technique. Do you have a good module or a script I could use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have so many options:

1. [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug#imgaug)
2. [albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations#albumentations)
3. [Augmentor](https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor#installation)
4. OpenCV:

   [Image-Augmentation-Using-OpenCV-and-Python-Github-Repo](https://github.com/AISangam/Image-Augmentation-Using-OpenCV-and-Python)

   example code I use before:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import imutils

def data_augmentation(img, min_rot_angle=-180, max_rot_angle=180, crop_ratio=0.2, smooth_size=3, sharp_val=3, max_noise_scale=10):
    (H, W) = img.shape[:2]
    img_a = img

    all_func = ['flip', 'rotate', 'crop', 'smooth', 'sharp', 'noise']
    do_func = np.random.choice(all_func, size=np.random.randint(1, len(all_func)), replace=False)
    #do_func = ['crop']
    # Filp image, 0: vertically, 1: horizontally
    if 'flip' in do_func:
        img_a = cv.flip(img_a, np.random.choice([0, 1]))
    # Rotate image
    if 'rotate' in do_func:
        rot_ang = np.random.uniform(min_rot_angle, max_rot_angle)
        img_a = imutils.rotate_bound(img_a, rot_ang)
    # Crop image
    if 'crop' in do_func:
        (H_A, W_A) = img_a.shape[:2]
        start_x = np.random.randint(0, int(H_A * crop_ratio))
        start_y = np.random.randint(0, int(W_A * crop_ratio))
        end_x = np.random.randint(int(H_A * (1-crop_ratio)), H_A)
        end_y = np.random.randint(int(W_A * (1-crop_ratio)), W_A)

        img_a = img_a[start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y]
    # Smoothing
    if 'smooth' in do_func:
        img_a = cv.GaussianBlur(img_a, (smooth_size, smooth_size), 0)
    # Sharpening
    if 'sharp' in do_func:
        de_sharp_val = -(sharp_val - 1) / 8
        kernel = np.array([[de_sharp_val]*3, [de_sharp_val, sharp_val, de_sharp_val], [de_sharp_val]*3])
        img_a = cv.filter2D(img_a, -1, kernel)
    # Add the Gaussian noise to the image
    if 'noise' in do_func:
        noise_scale = np.random.uniform(0, max_noise_scale)
        gauss = np.random.normal(0, noise_scale, img_a.size)
        gauss = np.float32(gauss.reshape(img_a.shape[0],img_a.shape[1],img_a.shape[2]))
        img_a = cv.add(img_a,gauss)
    # Keep shape
    img_a = cv.resize(img_a, (W, H))
    return np.float32(img_a)
```

5. Others:

   You can do DA with just tensorflow! more in this blog: [Data Augmentation in Python: Everything You Need to Know](https://neptune.ai/blog/data-augmentation-in-python)

Comment: Ok thanks, man. The nature of my dataset will make it unlikely that I will use data augmentation since I don't really need to increase the luminosity or warp the images but I will definitely check it out in the future. You're answer does convince me tough that using photoshop or a similar technique is a good idea.

Comment: @MauriceBekambo no problem, hope you achieve what you want || : )